# CTFont with CTStringAttributes and NSMutableAttributedString crashes my app in xamarin

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin, nsattributedstring, ctfont

I'm trying to create `NSMutableAttributedString` and set its properties with `SetProperties` method. But my app crashes with error,

```
MonoTouch.Foundation.MonoTouchException exception - NSInvalidArgumentException Reason: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xc305d00.*
```

Code:

```
var richTask = new NSMutableAttributedString ("Random");
var fda = new CTFontDescriptorAttributes {
    FamilyName = "Courier",
    StyleName = "Bold",
    Size = 18f
};
var fd = new CTFontDescriptor (fda);
var font = new CTFont (fd, 0);

var attrs = new CTStringAttributes { Font = font };
var range = new NSRange (0, 3);
richTask.SetAttributes(attrs, range);

_label.AttributedText = richTask;
```

This code is in the `GetCell` method of `UITableViewController`. I want to be able to change font or color only of the first 3-4 letters of the string.

I figured out that if I eliminate *Font* component and set another property, for example, *StrokeWidth*, it works fine

```
var attrs = new CTStringAttributes { /*Font = font*/ StrokeWidth = 5f };
```

So it seems that *font* is initialized somewhat incorrect. Why is that? Why does it crash my app?

Thanks for advance!

Comment: I had the same problem, and used (I think) `UIStringAttribute` instead. Let me post you a code example when I get to work.

Comment: I tried to repro this bug in a simple program, but I get the expected output (font and all).   Please provide the full repro.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an example of using `UIStringAttributes` instead:

```
        string line1 = "Don't have Facebook?", line2 = "\nCreate or sign in with an alternate account";
        var attributedString = new NSMutableAttributedString(line1 + line2);

        attributedString.SetAttributes(new UIStringAttributes
        {
            Font = Theme.BoldSmallFont,
            ForegroundColor = Theme.LightGray,

        }.Dictionary, new NSRange(0, line1.Length));

        attributedString.SetAttributes(new UIStringAttributes
        {
            Font = Theme.RegularSmallFont,
            ForegroundColor = Theme.LightGray,

        }.Dictionary, new NSRange(line1.Length, line2.Length));

        _alternateSignIn.SetAttributedTitle(attributedString, UIControlState.Normal);
```

This is an example of setting two different fonts on a `UIButton`. `Theme` is my own static class, you can replace the color and font with your own.

You should be able to accomplish the same thing with `UIStringAttributes` as with `CTStringAttributes`. You might post a bug report to Xamarin for your case that crashes: http://bugzilla.xamarin.com

*NOTE: attributed string only works on iOS 6 and higher. This is when Apple added these APIs.